# replicationcontroller not showed in kubernetes

Tags: nginx, docker, kubernetes

I've just installed Kuberentes on Vagrant (one master and one node).
I deployed 3 nginx pods:

```
$ ./cluster/kubectl.sh run my-nginx --image=nginx --replicas=3 --port=80
```

They were all running fine. I decided to delete one pod and a new pod was recreated immediatly (what I did expect). So it works fine. But the problem is that I can't see that replicationcontroller?

```
$ ./cluster/kubectl.sh get pods
NAME                         READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
my-nginx-2494149703-b18av    1/1       Running             0          22h
my-nginx-2494149703-l40qy    1/1       Running             0          22h
my-nginx-2494149703-tcw5v    1/1       Running             0          32m
```

but for rc nothing was showed

```
$ ./cluster/kubectl.sh get rc
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be running nginx in a different namespace. Try `./cluster/kubectl.sh get rc --all-namespaces`.